# Search-engine friendly DNS redirection

Tags: domain-name-system, seo, redirection

Is it possible to redirect one domain to another using DNS protocol (and not HTTP prococol), and that redirection being friendly to search engines?? i.e. such that search engines know that the two domains are the same website and not different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS doesn't have a redirection feature.  Two different domains (www and non-www are different) are seen by the search engines as different.

However, you can do a 301 redirect as a very early step at the HTTP level, which the search engines will follow and honor.

Comment: So CNAME and DNAME records are not redirections? Are they more like internally handled aliases?

Comment: They are not redirects, they are aliases. They handle the way names are translated into addresses, and don't affect what happens to web pages; a CNAME can be used to direct to a server which does virtual hosting and hosts different sites from another CNAME - I've used this technique lots myself.

Comment: Correct (@MarkR).  So that doesn't help SEO, but it does help with IP management.

Answer (score 1):

To know whether a redirection is search engine friendlyyou can use this tool:
http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php